# Routing loop issues

Tags: routing, adsl-router

I recently made a change to my Internet connection settings. Now, I am unable to open websites like facebook.com. I am also unable to login into Reddit. I think that should be solved once this is solved. It seems that it starts off loading facebook.com in the browser - the loading animation is shown but it never finishes loading. I did a traceroute to facebook.com:

```
/Users/snihalani/.oh-my-zsh on master 

➜ traceroute facebook.com

traceroute: Warning: facebook.com has multiple addresses; using 69.171.229.11

traceroute to facebook.com (69.171.229.11), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets

1  mygateway1.ar7 (192.168.1.1)  4.702 ms  0.563 ms  0.601 ms

2  117.204.160.1 (117.204.160.1)  43.279 ms  37.554 ms  35.270 ms

3  218.248.173.214 (218.248.173.214)  40.000 ms  37.003 ms  36.674 ms

4  115.249.204.174 (115.249.204.174)  60.928 ms  42.484 ms  42.325 ms

5  218.100.48.85 (218.100.48.85)  42.404 ms  49.217 ms  55.030 ms

6  218.100.48.85 (218.100.48.85)  48.231 ms  72.374 ms  47.914 ms

7  121.240.1.233 (121.240.1.233)  54.867 ms  43.686 ms  60.717 ms

8  59.165.191.41.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.41)  83.484 ms  83.794 ms  79.939 ms

9  59.165.191.41.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.41)  75.207 ms  78.766 ms  86.862 ms

10  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  102.627 ms  79.960 ms  85.063 ms

11  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  95.681 ms  89.692 ms  97.969 ms

12  * * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  99.014 ms

13  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  95.758 ms  102.054 ms  103.369 ms

14  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  108.403 ms  102.261 ms

15  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  104.780 ms *  102.340 ms

16  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  104.200 ms  122.036 ms  116.916 ms

17  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  123.851 ms *  119.757 ms

18  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  123.771 ms  127.903 ms *

19  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  122.568 ms  121.605 ms  124.061 ms

20  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  134.465 ms  142.017 ms *

21  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  131.524 ms  142.282 ms  134.590 ms

22  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  174.772 ms  154.446 ms  144.037 ms

23  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  149.381 ms *

24  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  165.386 ms  157.322 ms

25  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  147.382 ms  149.004 ms  153.029 ms

26  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  170.793 ms  176.437 ms  161.660 ms

27  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  172.803 ms  170.751 ms  171.698 ms

28  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  169.875 ms  172.243 ms  167.005 ms

29  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  181.745 ms  188.375 ms  178.656 ms

30  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  190.303 ms  185.341 ms  195.016 ms

31  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  173.274 ms  183.221 ms  174.645 ms

32  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  194.969 ms  193.557 ms

33  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  195.555 ms  186.773 ms

34  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  211.689 ms  190.998 ms  205.987 ms

35  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  224.556 ms  204.438 ms  204.317 ms

36  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  208.105 ms  225.779 ms  206.843 ms

37  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  208.030 ms  212.954 ms  218.306 ms

38  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  226.691 ms  218.892 ms  231.809 ms

39  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  218.534 ms  230.316 ms  218.266 ms

40  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  222.921 ms  219.308 ms  224.182 ms

41  * * *

42  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  248.052 ms  232.949 ms  246.116 ms

43  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  231.510 ms  238.345 ms  231.949 ms

44  * * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  251.609 ms

45  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  255.847 ms  251.343 ms *

46  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  256.130 ms  256.716 ms  253.809 ms

47  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  429.532 ms  272.758 ms

48  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  264.606 ms  271.306 ms *

49  * * *

50  * * *

51  * * *

52  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  279.853 ms  272.980 ms  283.237 ms

53  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  294.952 ms  293.773 ms *

54  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  302.733 ms  295.236 ms  298.335 ms

55  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  288.911 ms  294.908 ms  294.096 ms

56  * 59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  303.433 ms  305.602 ms

57  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  302.380 ms  304.698 ms  302.762 ms

58  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  318.363 ms  315.908 ms  305.647 ms

59  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  317.929 ms  314.558 ms  317.473 ms

60  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  349.696 ms  323.500 ms  331.816 ms

61  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  331.616 ms  331.479 ms  334.314 ms

62  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  336.972 ms  354.438 ms  338.948 ms

63  59.165.191.33.man-static.vsnl.net.in (59.165.191.33)  329.813 ms  335.307 ms  341.142 ms

64  59.163.16.54.static.vsnl.net.in (59.163.16.54)  330.766 ms  341.343 ms  338.912 ms
```

It looks like I am stuck in a routing loop due to bad routing tables in one of the routers on my way to Facebook.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should consult your Internet provider (TATA Communications, accoding to RIPE lookup) because there is a routing loop between two or three routers (I didn't count.) There is nothing you could do for yourself, as an end user.

Comment: We call this problem "something on the Internet is broken". In this case, `vsnl.net.in` doesn't seem to be able to reach at least some parts of Facebook's network.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could have played with [RIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_Information_Protocol) settings or enabled [IGMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igmp) which could potentially cause a lot of loops (on the LAN as well as WAN) if not configured correctly. Also, "extrernal" RIP or IGMP is highly not recommended for consumer-grade gear such as your home router as it consumes a lot router processing cycles and the amount of information coming for the "external" network could be overwhelming.

Otherwise, it could potentially be that your ISP is experiencing some momentarily hiccups or there are some network problems in your neighborhood which accidentally coincide with the time u messed with your internet settings. Just like @Denis said.

Comment: I checked my router settings, It doesn't have RIP/IGMP enabled. Any other possibilities you can think of ?

Comment: Nope, srry. It should be ISP-related issues at this point I guess. You should contact them about the issue. Maybe a server/router of theirs is drunk somewhere.